# Can I specialize std::begin and std::end for the return value of equal_range()?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, iterator, template-specialization

The `<algorithm>` header provides `std::equal_range()`, as well as some containers having it as a member function. What bothers me with this function is that it returns a pair of iterators, making it tedious to iterate from the begin iterator to the end iterator. I'd like to be able to use `std::begin()` and `std::end()` so that I can use the C++11 range-based for-loop.

Now, I've heard contradictory information in regards to specializing `std::begin()` and `std::end()` - I've been told that adding anything to the std namespace results in undefined behavior, whereas I have also been told that you can provide your own specializations of `std::begin()` and `std::end()`.

This is what I am doing right now:

```
namespace std
{
    template<typename Iter, typename = typename iterator_traits<Iter>::iterator_category>
    Iter begin(pair<Iter, Iter> const &p)
    {
        return p.first;
    }
    template<typename Iter, typename = typename iterator_traits<Iter>::iterator_category>
    Iter end(pair<Iter, Iter> const &p)
    {
        return p.second;
    }
}
```

And this does work: http://ideone.com/wHVfkh

But I am wondering, what are the downsides to doing this? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **17.6.4.2.1/1** The behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it adds declarations or definitions to namespace `std` or to a namespace
>   within namespace `std` unless otherwise specified. A program may add a
>   template specialization for any standard library template to namespace
>   `std` only if the declaration depends on a user-defined type and the
>   specialization meets the standard library requirements for the
>   original template and is not explicitly prohibited.

So yes, I believe that, technically, your code exhibits undefined behavior. Perhaps you can write a simple class that takes a pair of iterators in its constructor and implements `begin()` and `end()` methods. Then you can write something like

```
for (const auto& elem: as_range(equal_range(...))) {}
```

Comment: Exactly how 'picky' is the part about it being allowed if user-defined types are involved? The pair contains iterators which iterate over a container of unique_ptrs to my user-defined type.

Comment: Your definitions, as written, don't mention any user-defined types. These templates might eventually be instantiated with user-defined types, but that's irrelevant.

Comment: In any case, the "depends on user-defined types" escape hatch only applies to template specializations. Yours aren't: they are primary function templates, that just happen to overload other function templates with the same name.

Comment: Just adding, the template specialization exception is what allows us to specialize `std::hash`.